# About Cuda 1D convolution, How can I do this faster?

Tags: cuda

- int threads = 32;
- dim3 blocks(250000/31,129,50);
- coefsize = 129;

```
__global__ void D_Conv(float *in, float* coef, float *out, int coefsize)
{

    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 
    int j = blockIdx.y; //129
    int k = blockIdx.z; //50

    if (j < coefsize && i < 250000 && k < 50)
    {
        if (i - j >= 0 && i - j < 250000)
        {
            atomicAdd(&out[k*250000 + i], coef[j] * in[k*250000 + i - j]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Many people recommend convolution with FFT, but in this case, two array's sizes have wide variances( 129 and 250000). So convolution with FFT is slower than this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe atomics should be necessary here.  The only thread clashing you would have is in the `y` dimension, so we can simply reduce your overall grid (in  `y`) and convert the operation to a loop computing a running sum.  You have plenty of threads in your grid to saturate any GPU, even without the `y` dimension.

Here's an example:

```
$ cat t20.cu
#include <iostream>
#define TOL 0.1
__global__ void D_Conv(float *in, float* coef, float *out, int coefsize)
{

    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockIdx.y; //129
    int k = blockIdx.z; //50

    if (j < coefsize && i < 250000 && k < 50)
    {
        if (i - j >= 0 && i - j < 250000)
        {
            atomicAdd(&out[k*250000 + i], coef[j] * in[k*250000 + i - j]);
        }
    }
}

__global__ void D_Conv_i(float *in, float* coef, float *out, int coefsize)
{

    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    //int j = blockIdx.y; //129
    int k = blockIdx.z; //50

    if (i < 250000 && k < 50)
    {
        float s = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 129; j++)
          if  (i - j >= 0 && i - j < 250000) s += coef[j] * in[k*250000 + i - j];
        out[k*250000 + i] += s;
    }
}

int main(){
  int num_c = 50;
  int csz = 250000;
  int coefsize = 129;
  int isz = num_c*csz;
  int osz = num_c*csz;
  float *d_in, *h_in, *d_coef, *h_coef, *d_out, *h_out, *h_out_i;
  cudaMalloc(&d_in,   isz*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_out,  osz*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_coef, coefsize*sizeof(float));
  h_in    = new float[isz];
  h_out   = new float[osz];
  h_out_i = new float[osz];
  h_coef  = new float[coefsize];
  cudaMemset(d_out, 0, osz*sizeof(float));
  for (int i = 0; i < coefsize; i++) h_coef[i] = i%5;
  for (int i = 0; i < isz; i++) h_in[i] = i%4;
  cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, isz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_coef, h_coef, coefsize*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  int threads = 128;
  dim3 blocks((csz+threads-1)/threads, coefsize, num_c);
  D_Conv<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_in, d_coef, d_out, coefsize);
  cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, osz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  dim3 blocks2((csz+threads-1)/threads, 1, num_c);
  cudaMemset(d_out, 0, osz*sizeof(float));
  D_Conv_i<<<blocks2, threads>>>(d_in, d_coef, d_out, coefsize);
  cudaMemcpy(h_out_i, d_out, osz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < osz; i++) if (fabsf(h_out_i[i] - h_out[i]) > TOL) {std::cout << "mismatch at: " << i << " was: " << h_out_i[i] << " should be: " << h_out[i] << std::endl; return 0;}
}
$ nvcc -o t20 t20.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t20
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ nvprof ./t20
==14221== NVPROF is profiling process 14221, command: ./t20
==14221== Profiling application: ./t20
==14221== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   53.54%  43.853ms         2  21.926ms  21.863ms  21.989ms  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
                   26.97%  22.087ms         1  22.087ms  22.087ms  22.087ms  D_Conv(float*, float*, float*, int)
                   17.30%  14.172ms         2  7.0860ms  1.4400us  14.171ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
                    2.04%  1.6702ms         1  1.6702ms  1.6702ms  1.6702ms  D_Conv_i(float*, float*, float*, int)
                    0.14%  118.24us         2  59.122us  56.386us  61.858us  [CUDA memset]
      API calls:   75.11%  270.97ms         3  90.322ms  189.31us  270.50ms  cudaMalloc
                   23.11%  83.367ms         4  20.842ms  45.694us  44.579ms  cudaMemcpy
                    1.07%  3.8698ms         4  967.45us  449.83us  2.5106ms  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.59%  2.1262ms       404  5.2620us     332ns  230.46us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.06%  223.31us         4  55.828us  47.710us  74.669us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.03%  98.648us         2  49.324us  31.800us  66.848us  cudaMemset
                    0.02%  86.603us         2  43.301us  13.778us  72.825us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.01%  21.169us         4  5.2920us  3.2030us  8.0240us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  11.459us         8  1.4320us     427ns  4.2700us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  3.6360us         3  1.2120us     563ns  1.6820us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  2.7220us         4     680ns     520ns     877ns  cuDeviceGetUuid
$
```

(CUDA 11.1U1, Tesla V100)

we can see that the atomic kernel takes over 20ms, whereas the non-atomic kernel runs in less than 2ms.  Also note that I am running with 128 threads per block rather than 32.  Not sure why you chose 32, I would aim for 64 or higher.

Because the size of `coef` array is relatively small, and the access pattern is uniform across the warp, we can take advantage of `__constant__` memory for this data.  This gives an additional speed-up:

```
$ cat t20.cu
#include <iostream>
#define TOL 0.1
__global__ void D_Conv(float *in, float* coef, float *out, int coefsize)
{

    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockIdx.y; //129
    int k = blockIdx.z; //50

    if (j < coefsize && i < 250000 && k < 50)
    {
        if (i - j >= 0 && i - j < 250000)
        {
            atomicAdd(&out[k*250000 + i], coef[j] * in[k*250000 + i - j]);
        }
    }
}
__constant__ float Ccoef[129];
__global__ void D_Conv_i(float *in, float* coef, float *out, int coefsize)
{

    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    //int j = blockIdx.y; //129
    int k = blockIdx.z; //50

    if (i < 250000 && k < 50)
    {
        float s = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 129; j++)
          if  (i - j >= 0 && i - j < 250000) s += Ccoef[j] * in[k*250000 + i - j];
        out[k*250000 + i] += s;
    }
}

int main(){
  int num_c = 50;
  int csz = 250000;
  int coefsize = 129;
  int isz = num_c*csz;
  int osz = num_c*csz;
  float *d_in, *h_in, *d_coef, *h_coef, *d_out, *h_out, *h_out_i;
  cudaMalloc(&d_in,   isz*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_out,  osz*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_coef, coefsize*sizeof(float));
  h_in    = new float[isz];
  h_out   = new float[osz];
  h_out_i = new float[osz];
  h_coef  = new float[coefsize];
  cudaMemset(d_out, 0, osz*sizeof(float));
  for (int i = 0; i < coefsize; i++) h_coef[i] = i%5;
  for (int i = 0; i < isz; i++) h_in[i] = i%4;
  cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, isz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_coef, h_coef, coefsize*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(Ccoef, h_coef, coefsize*sizeof(float));
  int threads = 128;
  dim3 blocks((csz+threads-1)/threads, coefsize, num_c);
  D_Conv<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_in, d_coef, d_out, coefsize);
  cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, osz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  dim3 blocks2((csz+threads-1)/threads, 1, num_c);
  cudaMemset(d_out, 0, osz*sizeof(float));
  D_Conv_i<<<blocks2, threads>>>(d_in, d_coef, d_out, coefsize);
  cudaMemcpy(h_out_i, d_out, osz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < osz; i++) if (fabsf(h_out_i[i] - h_out[i]) > TOL) {std::cout << "mismatch at: " << i << " was: " << h_out_i[i] << " should be: " << h_out[i] << std::endl; return 0;}
}
$ nvcc -o t20 t20.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t20
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ nvprof ./t20
==2191== NVPROF is profiling process 2191, command: ./t20
==2191== Profiling application: ./t20
==2191== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   54.38%  44.047ms         2  22.024ms  21.997ms  22.051ms  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
                   27.25%  22.075ms         1  22.075ms  22.075ms  22.075ms  D_Conv(float*, float*, float*, int)
                   17.15%  13.888ms         3  4.6294ms  1.4720us  13.885ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
                    1.07%  869.88us         1  869.88us  869.88us  869.88us  D_Conv_i(float*, float*, float*, int)
                    0.15%  117.83us         2  58.913us  56.321us  61.505us  [CUDA memset]
      API calls:   77.28%  307.94ms         3  102.65ms  188.61us  307.49ms  cudaMalloc
                   20.70%  82.467ms         4  20.617ms  48.300us  44.617ms  cudaMemcpy
                    1.27%  5.0520ms         4  1.2630ms  593.63us  3.2465ms  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.62%  2.4765ms       404  6.1290us     450ns  261.77us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.07%  271.54us         4  67.884us  59.173us  88.716us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.02%  97.041us         2  48.520us  30.831us  66.210us  cudaMemset
                    0.02%  86.276us         2  43.138us  14.800us  71.476us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.01%  23.142us         1  23.142us  23.142us  23.142us  cudaMemcpyToSymbol
                    0.01%  21.576us         4  5.3940us  3.0900us  8.4600us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  13.604us         8  1.7000us     667ns  4.4800us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  5.7060us         3  1.9020us     452ns  3.5840us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  3.2440us         4     811ns     660ns  1.0340us  cuDeviceGetUuid
$
```

The improved kernel now runs in less than 1ms, for a ~20x speed-up.

Comment: Thank you so much~!!  Your answer was good help for me.
Sir, can I ask one more Question?
I wanted to study Cuda Parallel programming, so I surfed a lot.
But I can't find why "for loop" is faster than atomic (in this case) . How did you know this contents?

Comment: Atomics are generally not as fast as ordinary memory operations. You can study "atomics, reductions, warp shuffle" [here](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/) if you want to learn that.